# Why may Russians compete in world championships?

Tags: doping

A few months ago it was announced that Russian athletes in all sports were banned from world championships and the Olympic games.

Since then, I have seen many Russians still compete in such events. For instance, the ISU world championships speed skating.
Why can they still participate?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Who are the "Olympic Athletes from Russia"?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/who-are-the-olympic-athletes-from-russia)

Comment: No, this relates to the latest ban of second half 2019. Not the ban from 2018.

Answer (score 1):

As with the athletes at the focus of [this earlier question on Sports Stack Exchange](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/17786/who-are-the-olympic-athletes-from-russia),

- the national association is banned from involvement. This means no organisational presence, no Russian flag, no Russian anthem;
- some individuals have specific bans, including a variety of athletes, coaches and training staff, and senior administrators (some for covering up doping, but a small number for possible doping in their time as athletes);
- individual athletes may (apply for and receive dispensation to) compete on their own, by proving they are not involved in any doping.

[This contemporary BBC article](https://www.bbc.com/sport/olympics/50710598) describes the decision similarly and quotes relevant person's outlining:

> But athletes who can prove they are untainted by the doping scandal will be able to compete under a neutral flag.
>
> ...
>
> However, Travis Tygart, chief executive of the US Anti-Doping Agency, said not imposing a blanket ban on all participation by Russian athletes - even under a neutral flag - is a "devastating blow" to clean athletes.
>
> ...
>
> Triple Olympic medallist Kelly Sotherton, who was retrospectively awarded her 2008 heptathlon bronze after Russia's Tatyana Chernova failed to have a doping ban overturned, says she understands why tougher sanctions were not imposed.
>
> "I think they are thinking of the majority of athletes who are doing the right thing, not the wrong thing," she said.